# Large data set including several dependent variables

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I have a data set which includes several variables such as `ID, x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4` and was collected over ten years. We asked people several questions regarding their health conditions, and then we took their blood and checked the value of `y1,y2,y3,y4`. So the data set could include the information of a subject (ID) several times. Now I was wondering how I can find the relationship between `x1,x2,x3,x4` with each of these dependent variables. Which statistical method do I need to use for analysis? When I have several dependent variables, do I need to check the relationship of `Xs` with each `y` separately? Does time has a role as a factor in this analysis? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The relationship analysis would depend on what the `ys` are. (Please mention them in the question.) For instance, if `ys` are lets say, blood cancer, lung cancer etc, may be it would be possible to make a combined `y` for occurrence of cancer in general. Also as it is a time kinetics, time would likely be a important factor in the analysis.

Comment: @rraadd88, thanks so much for the comment. 1. What statistical method I should use when Time is a factor? 2. Suppose y1 is Cholesterol, y2 is Iron and etc.

Comment: As far as I know time is just another `x` in your data. I am not aware of methods which are specific to utilisation of time factor.